# Date time from absolute numbers (in relation to set date)

Tags: r

I have a data set which has the date in absolute numbers after the first case's occurrence, such as:

```
date  v1 v2
1     a  b
1     a  f
2     a  b
3     a  D
4     d  b
3     c  b
```

As `date = 1` corresponds with a set date, say `1999-10-15`, I would like to translate that into readable dates but don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Try `as.Date(df1$date, origin = "1999-10-14")`

Comment: probably @akrun has understood your question in detail and this is likely the solution, because - it's akrun ;) But I did not really understand it. What do you mean with 'set date' - is this (as probably interpreted by akrun) meant to be the distance in  days to a original day? or does every number represent a date independent of this date? In this case you could simply merge the data frame with the key... ?

Comment: Basically, as @akrun perfectly addressed, this was the solution. What I meant was: the data set has introduced its own numbering of days, starting from 0 (corresponding to a specific day) and then simply numbering up from that day.

Comment: yeah, after posting my comment, I actually saw this in your question oops.

Comment: Is there a way to let the function know the value of missing values (i.e. if I don't want `99` to be interpreted as a date but instead as `NA`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function recognizes NA values, so you can do use `df$date[df$date == 99] <- NA` and `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, origin = "1999-10-14")`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using
`as.Date(df$date, origin = "1999-10-14)`, where the value passed to `origin` corresponds with the value `0` in the absolute numbers.

Comment: Ok, this has also been said by @akrun, sorry!